# does a wrong src in the img tag overloads the server?

Tags: html, lighttpd, performance

I have this on a very big number of pages: src="//avatar/images/...";

this server is serving zillions of files I was wondering if it's wise to fix that double slash inside the img tag.

I would do it at least for an aesthetic point of view, but my question is: "does it affects the http request in some way?"

the backend server is Lighttpd

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double slash is not likely to cause performance issues; I have however seen webservers error out on it (i.e. giving 404s). If it's working for you, no reason to touch it, really.

However, cleaning up is always good!